# simple_html_dom plaintext result has no spaces

Tags: php, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I have the following html:

`<div><p>Launched:</p> <p>2010</p><p>Categories:</p><p>Software</p><p>Description:</p><p>Established</p><p>Website:</p></div>`

if I load it and use plaintext to get just the text:

`$str = '<div><p>Launched:</p><p>2010</p><p>Categories:</p><p>Software</p><p>Description:</p><p>Established</p><p>Website:</p></div>';
$html = str_get_html($str);
echo $html->plaintext;`

The result is without spaces between the different p tags:

Launched:2010Categories:SoftwareDescription:EstablishedWebsite:

If I add a space between the closing and opening p tags, it outputs correctly.

Is that a right behavior?

Is there a way to get the parser to consider p tags in the plaintext output?

Comment: yes it is the right behavior.

Comment: So what should I do, if I want a readable output?

Comment: then use `->innertext` instead

Comment: @bansi: if I add spaces between the tags, which shouldn't make any difference, it adds spaces between the words in the output

Comment: @AlonDor I removed my comment, as it is confusing. The space between the `</p> <p>` tag is part of the `<body>...</body>` tag so it becomes a space in your text when you strip off the tags.

Comment: How about replacing every `><` with `> <`

Comment: @pguardiario, that is exactly what I've ended up doing!

Answer (score 0):

You must have the space between the tag p , or you can do as this:

```
$result = "";
foreach($html->find('p') as $val){
    $result .= $val->plaintext." " ;
}
```

Comment: this was just an example, I'm actually parsing a whole page, and I want to get just the text from it, for most cases plaintext works just fine, but sometimes, if the HTML has consecutive tags (not just p tags), the output has attached words. Is there a way to workaround it?

Answer (score -1):

u may strip the tags in this way

```
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $rawContent = strip_tags($content);
    $html = str_get_html($content);
```